# More succinct code example

Tags: c#

Is there a more succinct way of writing this?

```
articleCount += 1;
if (articleCount > 4)
{
    // Reset counter to 1
    articleCount = 1;
}
```

Comment: Your code part looks enough efficient for me. And would be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
if (++articleCount > 4) articleCount = 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who like <s>mathematical puzzles</s> unreadable code, the following would work as well:

```
articleCount = (articleCount % 4) + 1;
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find that this is the most elegant solution